# Getting logged out of user account upon execution of a program

Tags: ubuntu, login, skype, 32bit

On my friend's computer when Skype is launched either via terminal or GUI the current user is forced to log out of the system.  Purging and reinstalling Skype did not work and we are using the same version of Ubuntu, that is 12.04.4 LTS 32-bit, and both our installed Skype programs are of the same version, namely 4.2.0.11.

What may be the cause behind this and how can this behaviour of Skype avoided? Is it a bug or something related with installed programs etc. ? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

The log files are as follows and my friend also stated that when he tried to have a look at these files in Emacs he got kicked out of the system again:

**skype-err.log**

```
skype: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
```

**.xsession-errors**

```
Warning: Only changing the first 12 of 24 buttons.

(gnome-settings-daemon:6738): power-plugin-WARNING **: gnome-session is not available
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area
Initializing wall options...done
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/jack/.compiz/session/102004b2d250ec54c7139932580828939400000066890035"
Initializing session options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done
Initializing staticswitcher options...done
** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing scale options...done

(compiz:6756): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/sa$
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.


Initializing unityshell options...done
Setting Update "main_menu_key"
Setting Update "run_key"
Setting Update "run_command_terminal_key"
Setting Update "icon_size"
** Message: moving back from GtkStatusIcon to indicator

** (zeitgeist-datahub:7185): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:227: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
[7193:7193:0506/003710:ERROR:nss_util.cc(853)] After loading Root Certs, loaded==false: NSS error code: -8018

** (nautilus:6770): WARNING **: Error calling current_status: Method "current_status" with signature "" on interface "com.ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.Status" doesn't ex$


** (nautilus:6770): CRITICAL **: syncdaemon_status_info_get_online: assertion `SYNCDAEMON_IS_STATUS_INFO (sinfo)' failed
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Cpu: 6.37.2, x4, 2267Mhz, 3887MB
[000:000] Computer model: Not available
[000:003] Warning(clientchannel.cc:472): 0xb8304550: Unreadable or no port file.  Could not initiate GoogleTalkPlugin connection
[000:003] 0xb8304550: SendConnectStatus: Connect Status:
[
        "f-connect",

        {
                "error" : -1,
                "step" : "0"
        }
]

[000:004] Warning(clientchannel.cc:445): 0xb8304550: Could not initiate GoogleTalkPlugin connection
[000:004] 0xb8304550: GoogleTalkPlugin not running. Starting new process...
[000:004] Starting Flute
[000:004] Warning(pluginutils.cc:268): Failed to get GoogleTalkPlugin path. Trying default.
[000:006] Started GoogleTalkPlugin, path=/opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin
[000:006] 0xb8304550: SendConnectStatus: Connect Status:

[
        "f-connect",

        {
                "error" : -1,
                "step" : "0"
        }
]

[000:004] Warning(clientchannel.cc:445): 0xb8304550: Could not initiate GoogleTalkPlugin connection
[000:004] 0xb8304550: GoogleTalkPlugin not running. Starting new process...
[000:004] Starting Flute
[000:004] Warning(pluginutils.cc:268): Failed to get GoogleTalkPlugin path. Trying default.
[000:006] Started GoogleTalkPlugin, path=/opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin
[000:006] 0xb8304550: SendConnectStatus: Connect Status:
[
        "f-connect",

        {
                "step" : "2"
        }
]

[000:006] 0xb8304550: Waiting for GoogleTalkPlugin to start...
[001:108] 0xb8304550: Attempting to connect to GoogleTalkPlugin...
[001:108] Read port file, port=55429
[001:108] 0xb8304550: SendConnectStatus: Connect Status:
[
        "f-connect",

        {
                "step" : "0"
        }
]

[001:109] 0xb8302d20:  sending cookie Z2CZ//Bddv3VJWxk
[001:109] 0xb8304550: SendConnectStatus: Connect Status:
[
        "f-connect",

        {
                "step" : "1"
        }
]

[001:110] 0xb8304550: Initiated connection to GoogleTalkPlugin
[001:209] 0xb8304550: SendConnectStatus: Connect Status:
[
        "f-connect",

        {
                "step" : "3"
        }
]

[001:232] 0xb8304550: Socket connection established
[001:232] 0xb8304550: ScheduleOnlineCheck: Online check in 5000ms
[001:236] 0xb8304550: C->F: ["comment","BC state change: 2 to 3. Error? 0"]
[001:254] 0xb8304550: C->F: ["comment","BC state change: 3 to 4. Error? 0"]
[001:309] 0xb8302d20: Got cookie response, socket is authorized
[001:309] 0xb8304550: AUTHORIZED; socket handshake complete
[001:349] 0xb8304550: C->F: ["mf",2,{"appName":"googlemail","buildLabel":"gmail_fe_140429.00_p4","buildCl":"65973900","compileMode":"OPTIMIZED,LOCALE=tr","estima$
[001:353] 0xb8304550: F->C: ["fs",{"pr":"a"}]
[001:417] 0xb8304550: F->C: ["mf","mf5.3","5.3.1.0",2,{"audioCodecs":[[103,"ISAC",1,0,16000],[111,"opus",2,64000,48000],[104,"ISAC",1,0,32000],[109,"CELT",1,6400$
[001:435] 0xb8304550: C->F: ["getdevicestate"]
[001:441] 0xb8304550: F->C: ["getdevicestate","15","0",["__default_device","Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"],"0",["__default_device","High Definition Audio Control$
[001:589] 0xb8304550: C->F: ["jec",[[96,"H264-SVC",320,200,30]],{"num_threads":-1,"cpu_profile":1}]
[001:631] 0xb8304550: C->F: ["jf",[["stun.l.google.com","19302"]
,["alt3.stun.l.google.com","19302"]
,["alt2.stun.l.google.com","19302"]
,["alt4.stun.l.google.com","19302"]
,["alt1.stun.l.google.com","19302"]
]
,["CAESGwoSamFja2FyYXpAZ21haWwuY29tEN+V0YDdKBoQzrz8rti0zAEr12uU4bzj5g\u003d\u003d",["relay.google.com","19305","19305","443"]
]
[001:634] 0xb8304550: C->F: ["jec",[[96,"H264-SVC",640,400,30]],{"num_threads":-1,"cpu_profile":31}]
[006:260] 0xb8304550: HandleOnlineCheck: Starting check
[006:260] 0xb8304550: HandleOnlineCheck: OK; current state: 3
```

As far as I am concerned X is the culprit. I would like to hear you feedback and suggestions for possible remedies.

Thanks

Comment: Call Skype from the command line with something like `skype 2>~/skype-err.log &` then post the contents of `~/skype-err.log` and `~/.xsession-errors` where `~` is your home directory.

Comment: @JosephR. Thanks, I will have my friend do it ASAP and post the results.

Comment: Can you define "forced to lout of the system"? Does it crash? Will no further applications launch? Do they get a popup that says "you must log out"? What?

Comment: @Patrick The user gets logged out immediately and is presented with the log in screen.

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like X itself crashing.

Comment: @NathanOsman IMO the system is not that stable it just kicks the user out and presents with a login screen.

Comment: Yes this very much sounds like Skype is attempting to access a X resource or a component of the desktop and that is crashing, resulting in what appears to be a logout. In actuality X is designed that when it crashes it will respawn a new copy and present the user with a login screen.

Comment: @slm Thanks for the information. Would doing as Joseph told help us pinpoint the issue?

Comment: Perhaps but I'd look in the directory `/var/log` for any logs related to X. I'm using Fedora and it maintains this log file for example: `Xorg.0.log`, I would assume Ubuntu does the same. That file might shed more useful light on the issue.

Comment: @slm Yeah I confirm that Ubuntu also maintains these files in the same directory. I will contact my friend ASAP and have the results of these commands and logs available. Should he search for X Window Manager or X11?

Comment: @Vesnog - I would look for X.

Comment: @JosephR. The corresponding log files have been appended to the original post and it seems like X is the culprit.

Comment: May be related to graphics card drivers as seen [here](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2013/10/msg02110.html) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2073987). It seems that `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` would help enlighten us further as @slm has suggested.

Comment: @JosephR. I will have it attached ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

I know about this problem. And as usual, the culprit is widely deemed to be `nouveau`, the GPL NVidia driver.
@Vesnog, may I guess that your friend has a GeForce card built into his PC?
That would explain a lot. :)

Ah, and since you're on Ubuntu, the following line might cure the "problem" as well ;-)

```
$ sudo apt-get remove light-locker
```

This thing is really annoying, especially for modern monitors! I still wonder why it is still installed by default, as 98% of modern people are now using TFT monitors (LCD/LED) which do no longer know about the "burn-in" phenomenon.